# Post photo on Facebook group using graph api

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an android app for a Facebook group. Using the graph API, I can easily post a text status but when I upload a photo, it returns error saying

`(#100) The picture is not properly formatted`

If I use the same code to post to *my* wall, the photo upload works fine.

Is this an API restriction or there is a separate approach to upload a photo to a group?

Following is my code:

```
Request photoRequest = Request.newUploadStagingResourceWithImageRequest(session, bitmap, new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if (mProgress != null && mProgress.isShowing())
                mProgress.dismiss();

            if (response.getError() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, "Successfully shared on the group", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, "Facebook sharing error: " + response.getError().getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    Bundle params = photoRequest.getParameters();
    if(message != null) {
        params.putString("message", message);
    }
    if(imageBytes != null) {
        params.putByteArray("picture", imageBytes);
    }
    photoRequest.setParameters(params);
    photoRequest.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
    photoRequest.setGraphPath(Constants.URL_FEEDS);
    photoRequest.executeAsync();
```

**EDIT**
I'm using Graph API v2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `POST` request to `/<group-id>/feed` doesn't allow to upload a photo (which otherwise works for `/me/feed`). I finally got this working with the `/<group-id>/photos` edge as suggested. Following is my code - hoping that it helps some:

```
Request photoRequest = Request.newUploadStagingResourceWithImageRequest(session, bitmap, new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if (mProgress != null && mProgress.isShowing())
                mProgress.dismiss();

            if (response.getError() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, "Successfully shared on the group", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, "Facebook sharing error: " + response.getError().getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    Bundle params = photoRequest.getParameters();
    if(message != null) {
        params.putString("message", message);
        photoRequest.setGraphPath(Constants.URL_FEEDS);
    }
    if(imageBytes != null) {
        params.putByteArray("picture", imageBytes);
        photoRequest.setGraphPath(Constants.URL_PHOTOS);
    }
    photoRequest.setParameters(params);
    photoRequest.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
    photoRequest.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be possible to post a photo in a group.

> You can make a POST request to photos edge from the following paths:
>
> /{group_id}/photos
>
> When posting to this edge, a Photo will be created.

[Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo)
Return type

```
Struct {
    id: numeric string,
    post_id: token with structure: Post ID,
    }
```